# Lazy loaded from custom node module Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created a node module where I i have created common functionality. In main application I am using some modules from node modules as lazy loaded. When I am generating build with build optimizer my lazy loaded chunks are creating successfully but in vendor.js file lazy loaded code is still exist.

I want to remove code from vendor.js file which is lazy loaded.

Comment: Your questions is?

Comment: My code is getting duplicated. separated chunk is created for lazy module but same code is also exist in vendor.js file. I want to remove lazy loaded code from vendor chunk.